# Using class name in CSS value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently doing some styling and have thought up an interesting way to do something. I want to create a piece of text that stands out among every other bit of text on the page. Below you can see the way I've done this.

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^=impact]')[0],
  col = el.className.split('-')[1];

el.style.textShadow = '2px 2px 0 #' + col;
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UxB7TDq.jpg');
}
[class^=impact] {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 72pt;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<span class="impact-008080">impact</span>
```

As you can see I'm basically getting the first half of the class and applying styles to it and grabbing the second half of the class in JavaScript and applying the shadow then. What I want to do is omit the JavaScript completely and keep it all in CSS.

I do not have a list of colours. Any and all hex colours are supported obviously. I would prefer to keep this format.

Comment: Do you have a pre-defined list of colors (the second part)?

Comment: @Harry no, I should have mentioned that. I would really like to keep it in this format as well.

Comment: In that case I think it would be really tricky (and not to forget a hugely bloated file) to do it with CSS/Less. I am not much into SASS but I would assume the same applies for it too.

Comment: why not just use two classes?

Comment: @serakfalcon Because how would I select the colour class? There are 16581375 possible hex colours.

Comment: If you want to embed your styling in your HTML, just use the `style` attribute. Don't fool yourself into thinking your doing anything better by using embedding it in either the class attribute or a data-* attribute.

Comment: Did you look to see what CSS Preprocessors even *do*?  Considering Sass and Stylus files are never sent to the client and browsers don't "support" them, there's no possible way they can be aware of the DOM.

Comment: Questions are supposed to be asked *after* performing research.  Did you do *any*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## CSS `attr`

Theoretically, this type of thing is what the CSS `attr` property could be used for when browser support exists. Note that this won't work now, but when browser support does exist, it might look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<span class="impact" data-shadow="#008080">Impact</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.impact {
    /* you text and positioning styles here */

    text-shadow: 2px 2px attr(data-shadow);
}
```

You can read more about the `attr` property here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

---

## But for now...

Your best bet is probably to continue to use JavaScript, but instead of appending the hex code to the class name, store the hex value in a data attribute of the element, allowing you to keep the class name consistent for all instances of that element.

**HTML**

```
<span class="impact" data-shadow="#fff">Impact</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.impact {
    /* your text and position styles here */
}
```

**JS**

```
var el = document.querySelector(".impact"),
    shadow = el.dataset.shadow;

el.style.textShadow = '2px 2px ' + shadow;
```

Here's a JSFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/xx6r1n2o/