# Sass, css and content: attr()

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying use something like the following HTML:

```
<div class="cowPen" data-cows="moo">The cow says </div>
```

In css something like this:

```
.cowPen:after {
    content: attr(data-cows);
}
```

Which works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/m12tnfjs/)

However, when I try to create the same css via sass/compass, it doesn't work. The content attribute is removed entirely from the element, according to Chrome dev tools.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

P.S. I should add that I'm trying to implement the technique listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030509/using-class-name-in-css-value/26030959#26030959) but with sass compilation.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://sassmeister.com/gist/7b65521c20d307f0e9a7

Answer (score 1):

**SASS doesn't know or care about your HTML.** It's a CSS preprocessor.

Assuming SASS doesn't have it's own `attr()` function (which it doesn't), then this:

```
.cowPen:before {
    content: attr(data-before);
}
```

will render like this:

```
.cowPen:before {
    content: attr(data-before);
}
```

In other words, completely unchanged.

Comment: Which makes sense, I suppose, but the css doesn't know or care about the HTML either.

The path is sass compiliation->css->runtime interpretation, right? Sass just adds a step.

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The CSS itself doesn't, true, but the browser does. That's how CSS + HTML operates. Basically, the *preprocessor* doesn't care, but the *processor* does.

Comment: But that's the point. At runtime, the sass-generated css doesn't work but regular old css does.

Comment: Is the SASS compiling properly?

Comment: I think so: `.cowPen:before {content: attr(data-cows);}` should do it, right?

Comment: It certainly seems like it. That's odd.

Comment: So in other words, you can't reproduce the problem?  If that's the case, this question should be closed as reproducible, not answered with a non-answer.